# Access Control seems to be ignored when route is not found in Symfony

Tags: php, security, access-control, symfony

We have the following security settings for our symfony3 project:

```
firewalls:
    myfirewall:
        pattern: ^/myapi
        stateless: true
        http_basic: ~
        anonymous: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/myapi, ips: ['192.168.0.155'], roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/myapi, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Besides that there is a in memory provider. This works fine when routes are hit. A call to /myapi/resource/123 is protected. But unfortunately, /myapi/res is not. A request to this URI results in a 404.

This way the bad guys are able to determine whether a resources exists or not.

Does anyone know why this happens/what is wrong? I am a little bit clueless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, seems like Fabien did it :-/ https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8414

Although truly not a that big security issue, this does not give us the freedom to design our APIs the way we want.

Comment: By replacing the class of "security.firewall" using compiler passes, we were able to change the priority of the subscribed events, so the firewall listener gets called before the router listener, now.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

Works for us so far..